# Complex Analysis: Prove $\mathrm{d}f$ is irrelevant of coordinate.

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f\in C^\infty$ is defined on $\overline{\mathbb{C}}$. For change of variables $z = 1/w$, show that $$\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm{d}z + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\mathrm{d}\bar{z} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\mathrm{d}w + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{w}}\mathrm{d}\bar{w}.$$ This indicates that $\mathrm{d}f$ is irrelevant of the coordinate.

---

As I learned from complex analysis, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}$ are defined *formally* so that $\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm{d}z + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\mathrm{d}\bar{z}$ holds. In this light, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{w}}$ should also be defined to satisfy $\mathrm{d}f =\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\mathrm{d}w + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{w}}\mathrm{d}\bar{w}$. Then, how can I make use of the condition $z = 1/w$?

A more conceptual question might be, how should I understand $\mathrm{d}f$ is irrelevant of the coordinate?